# There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm working on a wordpress plugin and I'm having an error message

> There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Despite the activation of the debugging i'm unable to get more informations about the errors I have.

Here's the code implemented in my wp_config

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/logs/wordpress-errors.log' );
```

So what can I do ?

Comment: check server error logs

Comment: Did you check the  site admin email inbox?

Comment: You set your log path to **/logs/wordpress-errors.log** if it is not exists then try to look at **wp-content/debug.log**.

Comment: I haven't received a mail and the debug.log file doesn't contain a new error